# I'm looking for a word like "switchyard"

Tags: synonyms

I would like it to evoke:

1. Queuing up of the train cars,
2. Determining where each should go,
3. Building lines of cars with similar destinations, and
4. Sending them on their merry way (once there are enough cars to make it worthwhile).

I'm looking for something even shorter than "switchyard". In my case, I'm talking about chunks of data, not train cars.

Specifically, I'm looking for a concise name to give to a module of C-language code I'm working on. Other functions will provide assorted data to this module, which will sort it by destination and queue it up. When a given queue reaches a size threshold, the data is wrapped into a packet and sent to another function.

Thanks!

Comment: _Queuenode_, inevitably spelled _Q node_, _qnode_, or _qn_. It's the queueing yard, and it hasta be a major node in any system. Or take a term from game theory and call it a _saddle point_.

Comment: Given that you're talking about packets of data rather than railway cars, you've basically described the function of a [switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch).

Comment: simply "yard", which is what Railways People call them.  if you're "talking about chunks of data" you've described essentially all of computer science.  Simply state what system, language, and software thou are working on.  there's specific terms in each case for that sort of thing.

Comment: Assuming these train carriages are "figurative", and OP's really talking about a *[data] [packet switching*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_switching) context, perhaps where it all happens is a ***router***.

Comment: @JoeBlow True! I'm looking for a concise name to give to a module of C-language code I'm working on. Other functions will provide assorted data to this module, which will sort it by destination and queue it up. When a given queue reaches a size threshold, the data is wrapped into a packet and sent to another function.

Comment: I'd call it theBarrel. or, thePacketizer

Comment: guys switches and routers, I think, don't generally "stack up" stuff, they just, well, switch it and route it.  he's just talking about a "queue", a FIFO queue or whatever

Comment: (also just FWIW i've never heard "saddle point" / prisoner's dilemma used in this way)

Comment: I like thePacketizer :)  I might just get boring and call it Queue...

Comment: The usual railway term is 'marshalling yard'.

Comment: Is that a kind of *hub?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some contexts, a "buffer" or a "silo" provide the container for just this sort of functionality.  It's not too much of a stretch to call the module "buffer" (used as a  verb).

Answer (score 3):

A more automated type of train switchyard is the hump yard. Cars are pushed up a small hill and gravity takes over, laser scanners ID the car (and contents) and signal downhill switches to route the car to the appropriate tracks.
Call your code module "hump yard".

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere near as evocative as you envisage, and a different metaphor, but perhaps you might like `outbox`.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is either "router", or "switch".

**Router:** a device which forwards data packets to the appropriate parts of a computer network

**Switch:** a computer networking device that connects devices together on a computer network, by using packet switching to receive, process and forward data to the destination device

If you call it "the routing module", everyone will know what you mean.